# Spurious mongodb driver logging in groovy script

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy

This is pretty strange.  I am running a groovy script using the mongodb driver, and if I run it several times, only some of them will cause an initial INFO message.

First here are my particular system stats:

```
Ubuntu 15.04 running on VirtualBox VM, x64
groovy version 2.4.12
JVM 1.8.0.121
mongo driver: 3.5.0 (also tried 3.4.3)
mongo server (running on localhost): 3.4.7
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

@Grab(group='org.mongodb', module='mongodb-driver', version='3.5.0')

import com.mongodb.*
import com.mongodb.client.*

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost")
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("demo")
MongoCollection assets = db.getCollection("assets")
println "count is ${assets.count()}"
```

and here are my results (my demo.assets collection has one document):

```
12:01 mongoTasks:schema: r
JassetsX
count is 1
12:02 mongoTasks:schema: r
JassetsX
Aug 29, 2017 11:02:04 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000     ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
count is 1
```

I only show two runs, but I can run it many times and maybe 20% of the time it gives that single INFO message.    I get more messages without the second setLevel after getting the client.

I have tried various other options I have seen in other questions, such as using SEVERE vs. OFF, as well as setting some system variables to shut off mongo logging.  I tried going back to 3.4.3 of the mongo driver, with no effect.  In some of the configurations, the initial INFO log appears 100% of the time, so 20% was the best I could get so far.

But wait, it gets better.  So I tried downloading the jar files and running it with straight java, and it never seems to get the INFO message!  Thinking maybe it has something to do with being a groovy script, I tried using compiled groovy (groovyc/groovy) with the same jar files, and then it goes to 100% failures (i.e. getting the INFO message on every run).  So it has something to do with groovy, and maybe the run-time binding of methods, but I am stumped as to where to look next.

So, for now I am going to go with compiled java, but I wonder if anyone has any ideas as to why it is doing the spurious messages with a groovy script.  I would like to figure this out because groovy/grape is quickly becoming my new scripting language.  I know there is a gmongo library, but it is pretty old (2015), and I'm not aware of an updated version.

Thanks